# How to unclog AC drain?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

The air handler primary drain is clogged and water is in the overflow pan under the air handler. The air handler is in my attic. The problem is all the videos I have seen show a T coupling that is connected to the primary drain and can easily blow out the drain from the top of T coupling. But my drain configuration doesn’t have the T coupling and is completely closed (see 2 pics).

Is it possible to clean the drain pipe without cutting and opening the primary drain pipe? I have not removed the air handler panels so I don’t know what the primary drain pipe connection looks like.

[image]

Comment: Attach a shop vac to the primary where it exits the house.   IMO the other pipe stubbed op on the left is not a good plan.   Dirty hot air is being drawn into air handler through it. I would have a cap on that .    Yiu could pour in some bleach water through the stub up while the vacuum is pulling the water out of the primary.     Is there a trap in the primary line near the air handler?

Comment: Examine the connections where your drain pipe goes into the pan. There might be one or two that are not glued but just shoved together so they can be taken apart later. I've cleaned many drains done that way.

Comment: Nair dissolves dust really well.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

Comment: Kris, I cannot get to the drain pipe where it exits the house because it drains into the roof gutter and the house is 2 stories high. There is no trap in the primary line. I will cap the pipe that is open.  So I can't blow out the drain line from the open pipe stub on the left?

Comment: Jack, the air handler is very tightly fit in the attic, and I can't locate where the water is overflowing into the pan.

Comment: I'm thinking that I should remove the panels and see what the pipe connections look like to the air handler? Maybe I can get access to the primary drain pipe and blow it out. The AC unit is about 20 years old and i had a clogged drain issue about 10 years ago, where the water in the pan overflowed and stained my ceiling. The guy that installed the AC unclogged the drain but I wasn't home to see how he did it. I AM MAKING SURE THAT THE PAN DRAIN IS UNCLOGGED!!